# Can jQuery UI 1.8.2 run on jquery 1.4.1?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, version, compatibility

It's that simple question.

Can jQuery UI 1.8.2 run on jquery 1.4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably possible, but I would not recommend that. Every jQueryUI update was developed after a new jQuery release, so it's most likely that they used at least some of the new features.

Answer (score 0):

Probably.

Why don't you test it?

Also, why don't you upgrade to the latest versions of both?

Comment: I'm concerned that upgrading to newer version might cause some problems on whole of my site and I don't have a log of where I've used jQuery UI on my site. Its a huge site.